# Do we have a way to limit database size in sqllite?

Tags: c++, sqlite

Below is some code that creates a sqlite database. Is there a way to limit the maximum size this database can grow to ?

```
int i, r;
sqlfs_t *sql_fs = calloc(1, sizeof(*sql_fs));
assert(sql_fs);
for (i = 0; i < (int)(sizeof(sql_fs->stmts) / sizeof(sql_fs->stmts[0])); i++)
{
    sql_fs->stmts[i] = 0;
}
r = sqlite3_open(db_file, &(sql_fs->db));
if (r != SQLITE_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open the database file %s\n", db_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_max_page_count) says:

> **PRAGMA max_page_count** = *N*;
>
> set the maximum number of pages in the database file.

(This setting applies to the connection; it is not permanent.)

Comment: Any other solutions ? Something we can do runtime ?